# TCP Packets in Raw socket - Centos 6.6

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I tried performing TCP traffic and capture that packets using RAW socket in other end .

I set window size to 50000 bytes. while sending the TCP traffic with max rate. I observe in wireshark around every 12 packets(1512 bytes packets) an ACk is send.

while receiving the packet in raw socket. i expected 12 packets as if i got in wireshark(i believe that wireshark also uses raw socket). But i was surprised to see one packet with send data stream.

To my knowledge, the RAW socket should receive in form of packets that is transmitted in wire and not as TCP streams.

I used below for raw socket to receive packet in port

```
  rawsd = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, ETH_P_ALL);
```

Is this anyway related to tcp_wrapper and OS tcp configuration.

Comment: What do you mean by whole junk ? Tcp sends and receives data in streams and not in packets what makes you think you would receive 12 packets ? Also i don't think wireshark uses raw sockets

Comment: Sorry junk means i receive it in whole stream not in packets.

I can understand TCP sends and recieves data in streams but RAW socket will capture in packets received on particular ports. 

Wirkshark uses libpcap which inturn uses RAW socket.

Comment: Yes right but then u will get the whole packet which you then would have to parse the headers get the packet length update the header pointers correctly to reach the data using libraries like libpcap i beleive

Comment: Then how is it possible for wireshark alone to show packets that are actually transmit in wire. Do you mean that RAW socket does get packet as such in lower layer.

Comment: On the wire they are bits. The lower layers of networking The driver in software perspective  does not care

Comment: What you need is to get the correct length of the packet from the ip header get the header length from tcp header update the pointer indexes in your buffer you read at to reach the data. Provided it is a data packet not handshake messages. My point is the junk u are talking about could be some header fields which are not ascii so you cannot read. That is the reason i asked about that.

Comment: My requirement is to get TCP packet count transmitted in wire which depend up on the MTU configured. I believe that it could be possible using RAW socket.

Comment: How are you going to handle handshake  and 4 way close messages and also congestion control algorithms tcp timers using raw sockets ?

Comment: This can be achieved using simultaneous handle of TCP socket for handshake and RAW socket to receives the packet capture info. Also reset the voting if this question is valid.

Comment: Anyways i don't think it is only dependent on mtu usually only mss maximum segment size is dependent on mtu. Which is negotiated at handshake so not really dependent upon local interface mtu

Comment: Ok i will. Sounds like u know what you are doing. You might need to edit the question for that though SO requires that and update it with how does the junk buffer look like after a recv on the socket

Comment: can you reset the voting as this in increase more users attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer i observed.

Linux Eth port have the configuration to set "tcp-segmentation-offload".

```
[root@Kernel317 home]# ethtool -k eth0
Features for eth0:
rx-checksumming: off
tx-checksumming: on
    tx-checksum-ipv4: off [fixed]
    tx-checksum-ip-generic: on
    tx-checksum-ipv6: off [fixed]
    tx-checksum-fcoe-crc: off [fixed]
    tx-checksum-sctp: off [fixed]
scatter-gather: on
    tx-scatter-gather: on
    tx-scatter-gather-fraglist: off [fixed]
tcp-segmentation-offload: on
    tx-tcp-segmentation: on
    tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off [fixed]
    tx-tcp6-segmentation: off [fixed]
```

On Enabling tcp-segmentation-offload, packets are clubbed together in eth port as full Data segment irrespective of MTU configured.

```
   ethtool -K eth1 rx on tx on
```

On disable tcp-segmentation-offload, packets are not processed in eth ports and packet of MTU size is received in RAW socket.

```
   ethtool -K eth1 rx off tx off
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think wireshark uses something named [Promiscuous mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode) on your network interface in this mode it can get packets in lower layers. but if you use raw socket you just read receive buffer data not packets.
The following code from libpcap(wireshark backend) git repository show that it use raw socket with alternative options.

```
pcap_activate_snoop(pcap_t *p)
{
int fd;
...
fd = socket(PF_RAW, SOCK_RAW, RAWPROTO_SNOOP);
```

Comment: is it so .. i think wireshark uses libpcap which inturn use RAW socket. If Raw socket then how can they show TCP in form packets and not streams.

Comment: I think this is completely out of track.

Comment: I added code from [libpcap git repository](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap). i hope this helps and sorry if the answer is incorrect.

Comment: Ok i went through the some website . came to know that libpcap is different from RAW socket. Also found that RAW socket capture packet irrespective of upper layer protocol. if so packet should be received as packet counts and not as stream.

Comment: I think packets buffered in kernel and if you want to read them as packets not stream you must use some kernel module to get packets. you can search libpcap git repository for keyword like RAW_SOCKET and read files contains the keyword to understand mechanism.

Comment: That was due to tcp-segmentation-offload.